# MSSQL Selecting top 10 but include columns with duplicate values

Tags: sql-server

Hi I'm trying to get the top ten winners of a competition by using the score. Problem is when there are two users with the same score for example I'm only getting the top 9 in effect (should be eleven records returned if there are two top 3 scores and the rest are unique for example)...

I'm not sure how to tackle this and would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks in Advance,

Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should be eleven records returned if there are two top 3 scores

Sounds like you want to use [`dense_rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825).

This will give you all the rows that is in the top 10 scores.

```
select T.Score
from (
       select Score,
              dense_rank() over(order by Score) as rn
       from YourTable
     ) T
where T.rn <= 10
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71913)

Comment: @Mikeal Indeed, rereading the question denserank is probably what's needed

Comment: Great, works a treat! Thanks. Learn something new every day... Sorry for the delayed response, it's only just gotten to the point where I need to implement this. I don't want to push my luck, but is there a way to include at least one category in the top 10, i.e. if there are 3 categories and all the top ten are from category one, I need to push down the last two from this category and then add the top 1 scores from category 2 and 3 to the result? Or would I need to do this via code (Using C#)

Comment: @lanc22 I guess it is possible but I don't fully understand what you want to do. You should ask this as a new question. In you new question you should include some sample data, the query you are using now (this dense_rank query) and the output you are looking for using the sample data.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I've posted a new question. Hope it makes sense ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023422/mssql-select-top-10-winning-scores-including-ties-and-at-least-one-from-each-ca

Answer (score 1):

You want to do like this:

```
SELECT TOP(10) WITH TIES
FirstName, LastName, score
FROM winners
ORDER BY score;
```

For further information see [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The top syntax allow ties

```
[ 
    TOP (expression) [PERCENT]
    [ WITH TIES ]
]
```

Did you try that?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx